# Mysql query to change values in one table according to another table values

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have 2 table like these:

1. > profile_active (col1=accounts)

2.

> profiles_inactive (col1=accounts, col2=inactive)

now,
i want table '2' to cross all the accounts with table '1' and if a mutual record is found then the query update the profiles_inactive.inactive to '1' and if not then change the filed to '0'.

i have no idea what kind of query or function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    profiles_inactive pi LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_active pa USING(accounts)
SET 
    pi.inactive = pa.accounts IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: but this query doesnt update to '1' or '0', and im not sure what you wrote there pi and pa